# finding the gcd without lists code not returning the desired output

Tags: python-3.x

I have been trying to learn algorithms and i have to do a basic program to find gcd of two numbers using python
so i wrote this code

```
def gcd_better(m, n):
    i = min(m, m)

    while i:
        if (m % i) == 0 and (n % i) == 0:
            return i
        else:
            i = i - 1



if __name__ == "__main__":
    gcd_better(4, 20)
```

here I want to return i but the code is not doin that
can anyone please help me understand is there anything wrong in my code

Answer (score 0):

Either `print` the answer in `gcd` or `return` a value, assign it to a variable in `main`, and print that

Since you're returning a value (`i`), do `print(gcd_better(4, 20))` to see what is being returned.